# I have a array of particular format i want to replace the keys as show below

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

The array is in following format. I tried some methods but I can't find a proper way to it.

I want to sent the below JSON through AJAX call, but I don't want the key 0,1 in both the child arrays.

```
[scheduleDetails] => Array
    (
        [2] => Array
            (
                [Wednesday] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [startTime] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 00:00
                                        [1] => 12:00
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [endTime] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 12:00
                                        [1] => 07:40
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
)
```

I want something like

```
             [scheduleDetails] => Array
            (

                [Wednesday] => Array
                    (

                                [startTime] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 00:00
                                        [1] => 12:00
                                    )


                                [endTime] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 12:00
                                        [1] => 07:40
                                    )



                    )

            )
```

what is the best method for that 
or in jquery also

```
       "scheduleDetails":[
        {"Friday":[{"startTime":["09:00","15:00"]},{"endTime":["13:00","21:00"]}]}],
```

like

```
     "scheduleDetails":[
      "Friday":["startTime":["09:00","15:00"]},{"endTime":["13:00","21:00"]]],
```

Comment: thanks this was my first time

Answer (score 0):

```
 "scheduleDetails":[
      "Friday":[{"startTime":["09:00","15:00"]},{"endTime":["13:00","21:00"]}]],
```

keep attention to open and close your arrays.

```
[,] -> array object
{}-> object
```